# r - gridtext::textbox_grob: character entities and pdf

Tags: character, entities

I have a problem with hyperlinks for pdf output. Character entities are not correctly taken into account in the pdf output. I tried a solution I found on the site :
https://stackoverfalow.com/questions/66348913/ggtextgeom-textbox-how-to-display-links-as-raw-text
It works for the "/" character but it doesn't work with "-" which I replace with "-". If I click on the address in the pdf, it is incorrect.

I also have a problem with @ which is not taken into account by textbox_grob.

Does anyone have a solution ?

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(grid)
library(gridtext)
library(gridExtra)

# Example with
link <- paste0(
  "Link :\n",
  "https:&#47;&#47;my&#45;example.com/dont&#45;work"
)

link_grob <- gridtext::textbox_grob(link,
                                    x = unit(0, "npc"),
                                    hjust = 0,
                                    vjust = 1,
                                    gp = gpar(fontsize = 5,
                                              col = "black"))

grDevices::pdf("Test.pdf",
               width = 8.27,
               height = 11.7)

gridExtra::grid.arrange(link_grob)

dev.off()
#> png 
#>   2


mail <- paste0(
  "E-mail: example-01@gmail.com"
)

mail_grob <- gridtext::textbox_grob(mail,
                                    x = unit(0, "npc"),
                                    hjust = 0,
                                    vjust = 1,
                                    gp = gpar(fontsize = 5,
                                              col = "black"))
#> Error: gridtext has encountered a tag that isn't supported yet: <a>
#> Only a very limited number of tags are currently supported.
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>